# With Puppeteer: How can I get an iframe from its parent element selector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I want to get an iframe as frame and click an element in the frame, but the iframe does not have a name and the website has many frames (`page.frames()` returns 14).

And I don't have permission to edit html. I can only edit the JavaScript.

I think the best way to identify the iframe in this case is from its parent element.

How can I do this with puppeteer?

```html
<div id="foo">
  <iframe>
    #document
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`elementHandle.contentFrame()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#elementhandlecontentframe) function to return a frame from an element handle.

**Quote from the docs:**

> Resolves to the content frame for element handles referencing iframe nodes, or null otherwise

**Example:**

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$('div#foo iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
```

Comment: great! I solved this with frame´s url, but your way is better. I will fix my code. thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Note that you should also add these browser startup options to run contentFrame method, otherwise it will return null:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'
    ]
});
```

Comment: See [Puppeteer iframe contentFrame returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65049531/puppeteer-iframe-contentframe-returns-null) for the full post of this answer

Answer (score 1):

Having an id of any element you can easily loop through its children and find all, that fulfill specific criteria, for example being an iframe. 
Filter function cannot be used, since this is not an Array, but a NodeList.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("foo");
var iframes = [];
for(var i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++){
  var child = parent.children[i];
  if(child.localName == 'iframe'){
    iframes.push(child);
  }
  };
console.log(iframes)
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <iframe>
    #document
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. But in this way, how can I click a iframe?

Comment: For a given element click() function should work, and you can use content​Document in order to get iframe's nodes.

Comment: noooo... I wrote this `const parent = document.getElementById('foo');  const framedom = parent.children[0].contentDocument;` and `framedom` is null. Is this wrong?

Comment: Are you trying this on real life example? Because for an example above it can be null, since it is not really #document.