# Puppeteer iframe contentFrame returns null

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have an interesting puppeteer problem that I'm not sure how to solve.

I have a webpage with an `iframe` on it. To get the iframe handle I do the following:

```js
const iframeHandle = await page.$('iframe')
```

To get the contentFrame I simply run:

```js
const frame = await iframeHandle.contentFrame()
```

However, this returns `null`.

I printed out the `iframeHandle` to make sure I got the correct element, and it does grab the correct iframe:

```js
console.dir(iframeHandle)
```

```
 _remoteObject: {
    type: 'object',
    subtype: 'node',
    className: 'HTMLIFrameElement',
    description: 'iframe',
    objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":5,"id":6}'
  },
```

Does anyone know how I can get the content of the iframe?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60000014/6243352) in [Puppeteer - How to fill form that is inside an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529201/puppeteer-how-to-fill-form-that-is-inside-an-iframe)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is with browser startup options. Add the following to "args":

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I was only able to get the frame by using `page.frames()` and then looping through to find the correct one. Accessing it in this way didn't require calling `.contentFrame()` at all.

```
const frames = await page.frames();
const frame = frames.find(f => f.url().includes('example.com'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, My answer may seem a bit strange and un-elegant but it works.. the idea is to evaluate code PURELY on the tab side and get data on your end just by seeing what certain things from the tab RETURN..

```
(async()=>{
  const src="https://github.com"
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: myExecutablePath, headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(src);
  await page.evaluate(`window.iframe=document.createElement('iframe');window.iframe.src='${src}';document.body.appendChild(window.iframe)`); //you get the idea, i made the iframe on the browser side
  const iframe=await page.evaluate(`window.iframe`);
  console.log(iframe);
  console.log("Above was your side iframe\nBelow is window side iframe");
  console.log(await page.evaluate(`window.iframe`));
})()
```

Comment: i know, i know, im not even trying to use the `.contentFrame` but I assume you wish to do something in the iframe, so i offered another way to do it *shrugs*

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
```

Comment: Please explain why this is helpful in the answer content.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$('#iframe');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
await frame.click('#introAgreeButton');
```

Answer (score 0):

use Chromium 89.0.4370, it work for me.